# Missing write permissions to the following paths: /var/www/html/pub/media

Tags: docker, magento, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

```
kubectl -n magento logs magento-install-jssk6
```

I am getting `Database found In ConfigModel.php line 166:Missing write permissions to the following paths: /var/www/html/pub/media` in install job:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: magento-install
  namespace: magento
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: install
      labels:
        app: magento-install
        k8s-app: magento
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: magento-setup
        image: kiweeteam/magento2:vanilla-2.3.4-php7.3-fpm
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args:
        - -c
        - |
          /bin/bash <<'EOF'
          bin/install.sh
          php bin/magento setup:perf:generate-fixtures setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/small.xml
          magerun index:list | awk '{print $2}' | tail -n+4 | xargs -I{} magerun index:set-mode schedule {}
          magerun cache:flush
          EOF
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: config
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/www/html/pub/media
          name: media
      volumes:
      - name: media
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: media
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Comment: What are the permissions on the path /var/www/html/pub/media ?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root      4096 Jul 24 08:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data    20 Feb 28 13:32 ..
drwx------ 2 root     root     16384 Jul 24 08:25 lost+found

Comment: and when I try to change permissions I am getting

chown: changing ownership of '/var/www/html/pub/media': Operation not permitted

Comment: What is the user running the `magento-setup` `CMD` ? You need to change permissions of `/var/www/html/pub/media` locally to the uid/gid of the user running inside your container.

Comment: I am not sure how to find that...I pulling images docker registry and don't have access to dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and when I try to change permissions I am getting chown: changing
> ownership of '/var/www/html/pub/media': Operation not permitted

It happens because you run `chown` as `www-data` user and the current owner of this directory is `root`.

You can resolve your issue by using the [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) run as `root` (user with id `0`). Below you can see a modified version of your `magento-install` `Job` with the **init cotntainer** already added:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: magento-install
  namespace: magento
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: install
      labels:
        app: magento-install
        k8s-app: magento
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: magento-chown
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        image: kiweeteam/magento2:vanilla-2.3.4-php7.3-fpm
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/pub/media']
        volumeMounts:
        - name: media
          mountPath: "/var/www/html/pub/media"
      containers:
      - name: magento-setup
        image: kiweeteam/magento2:vanilla-2.3.4-php7.3-fpm
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args:
        - -c
        - |
          /bin/bash <<'EOF'
          bin/install.sh
          php bin/magento setup:perf:generate-fixtures setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/small.xml
          magerun index:list | awk '{print $2}' | tail -n+4 | xargs -I{} magerun index:set-mode schedule {}
          magerun cache:flush
          EOF
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: config
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/www/html/pub/media
          name: media
      volumes:
      - name: media
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: media
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Once you attach to your newly created `Pod` by using:

```
kubectl exec -ti -n magento magento-install-z66qg -- /bin/bash
```

You'll see that the current owner of the `/var/www/html/pub/media` directory isn't any more `root` but `www-data` user:

```
www-data@magento-install-z66qg:~/html$ ls -ld /var/www/html/pub/media
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 27 18:45 /var/www/html/pub/media
```

We can simplify it even more. The **init container** doesn't even need to use the `kiweeteam/magento2:vanilla-2.3.4-php7.3-fpm` image. It might as well be a simple container based on `busybox`, which runs as `root` by default so you can omit the security context from the previous example and your `initContainers` section will look as follows:

```
initContainers:
- name: magento-chown
  image: busybox
  command: ['sh', '-c', 'chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/pub/media']
  volumeMounts:
  - name: media
```

The final effect will be exactly the same.